# Use a different favicon.ico on CSO

Tags: feature-request, jobs, favicon

The careers.stackoverflow.com icon is exactly the same as stackoverflow.com.  It's a problem when multiple tabs are open--it is not easy distinguish between SO and CSO.  Merely a different shade than the SO **orange** would do the trick.

**Grey**, of course is out, seemingly being the official MSO color.

**Brown**, the color of both waffles and ponies (conspiracy?) is too close to grey.

**Green**.  I like green.  It's my favorite color.

Answer (score 3):

Pink, as it's also for people who have been pink-slipped? (bad pun, but someone had to make it)

Comment: that was wrong! ..but very funny d:')

Answer (score 2):

What about blue? There are not enough blue logos in the computer industry.

[Breaking news! IBM just bought SO! http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/6213/ibmso.png](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/6213/ibmso.png)

[This just in! Google and Microsoft might be pulling their checks out to but SO out of IBM! http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/474/sogoogle.png](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/474/sogoogle.png)

Comment: Blue is Super User, though. Do you really want two SO family sites to have a blue logo?

Comment: When did IBM buy SO? :-)

Comment: You got the color order wrong for your Google joke.

Comment: It could have been a Microsoft joke :) I missed one blue, that I frankly didn't know how to cramp in there.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this, but I'm not sure how to distinguish it. While I (cough) *appreciate* (cough) voyager's design skills, I need to come up with a concept.

Remember it is a subdomain:

`careers.stackoverflow.com`

so you could argue that it's tightly related to SO, with the acct association, and all, and should have the same favico.

Comment: But, meta.so.com is a subdomain, uses the same OpenID and has a different favicon.

Comment: Just a different shade is all, me thinks.  Like MSO.  I'm not suggesting a totally different logo, just tweak the color of the favicon.ico so that CSO tabs are visibly different from SO tabs.

Comment: Can we also consider this for chat? With rooms, meta questions, rooms about meta questions and browser tabs, its getting a little difficult to navigate :)